# time dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo

I want to disable the past time in hours and minutes drop down. Please find the code i tried http://jsfiddle.net/7de4onun/18/.
I was able to disable past time from time dropdown list when displayed hours and minutes in a single drop down list. But how can i disable
past hours and minutes when hours and minutes are displayed separately in individual dropdown list as shown in fiddle based on the user selected date from date dropdown list.

Below is the sample code:

```
require([
           "dojo/_base/lang", "dijit/registry", "dojo/ready", "dijit/form/TimeTextBox", "dojo/parser"
       ], function(lang, registry, ready) {
           ready(function() {
               var timeH = registry.byId("selHours"),
               timeM = registry.byId("selMins");
               document.getElementById('selHours').value = document.getElementsByName('tHours')[0].value;
               document.getElementById('selMins').value = document.getElementsByName('tMinutes')[0].value;
            });
       });
```

Please find the full code here :http://jsfiddle.net/7de4onun/18/

PS: I want to disable hours and minutes which are already passed based on date user has selected, so that user cannot able to select the passed hour or minutes from the dropdown list.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7de4onun/19/

With below couple of changes you can achieve that

1. Added attribute "data-dojo-id" to both Hours and Minutes elements as below

   > ```
   > Hours: <input id="selHours" name="selHours" data-dojo-id="dojoSelHours"  />
   > Minutes: <input id="selMins" name="selMins" data-dojo-id="dojoSelMins" />
   > ```
2. In OracleDateTextBox control change handler you can see below change.

   ```
   onChange: function(v){
       setTimeout(showServerValue, 0);

       var currentTime=new Date();//new Date(v.getYear(), v.getMonth(), v.getDay(), 9, 25, 0);

       //Hour min constraints
       dojoSelHours.constraints.min= currentTime;

       //Minute min constraints
       dojoSelMins.constraints.min= currentTime;
   }
   ```

Comment: Its working in a wrong way..First is it is disabling the current hour and second is even if we select future hour for today's date, in the minutes dropdown list past minutes is disabled.See the updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7de4onun/21/ with your suggested modifications. @Venkata Panga

Comment: seems there is some issue with minutes in dojo, Please see update fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/7de4onun/22/

Comment: Issue with "dojo.1.9.0.js", I updated to "dojo.1.10.1.js", Please see update fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/7de4onun/25/